# My Xamarin app crashed in only-ipv6 environment

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

The version of Xamarin.form is 2.3.3.168.
I used **FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable** framework.

My app was rejected because:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 10.3 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

My app crashed in only-ipv6 environment when I just want to login to the MainPage, VisualStudio(My Os is win7) tells the errors below:

```
An error occurred while sending the request
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0047a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.6.0.10/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:383 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.6.0.10/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.6.0.10/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.6.0.10/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
```

I read many answers about app crashed in only-ipv6, but no one worked.

Maybe I don't understand their methods.

I tried to set 
[image]

but the result was still failure.

So I am so puzzled now.
Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead of ipv4 string in my code to a domain string, so the app doesn't crash no more.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more how did you solve this issue because my app built in Xamarin was rejected from App Store because of same thing? I don't have much experience with Xamarin. Thanks